# Who would receive US secretary of state in the airport in a foreign country?

Tags: united-states

Who would receive US secretary of state in the airport in a foreign country?

How is it determined?

Comment: After the edit, are you asking who would be waiting to pick him up?

Comment: @SamIam, the question before edit was supposed to ask the same question. And, answer to your question is: Yes.

Comment: @why  Since there are already answers here from when your questions seemed like a different question, it might be best to just make a new question.

Comment: @why even then, people may vote it as too broad, because it just _seems_ like a question that might have an unbounded number of potential answers.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on [James K's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/25703/2130), foreign officials are typically not part of a country's ceremonial order of precedence, with the exception of foreign ambassadors to the country in question (#10 on the [US list](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/25703/2130), #8 on the [Indian list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_order_of_precedence)).  Ambassadors have official standing from both their home country and from the government they're accredited to, so they belong to both country's sequences.

Guests are [typically](https://www.debretts.com/expertise/etiquette/formal-events/seating-plans-and-precedence/) seated next to the host, and would presumably stand next to them in a receiving line (if they're not travelling the line).

Thus, in this specific example, whoever arranged for Rex Tillerson's visit to India and Sri Lanka would be his official host.  Politicians don't just show up in another country (unless they're there on vacation and *not* meeting with the government).  Instead, they have an itinerary based on who they're meeting with, what they're going to be discussing, where they're staying, and so on.  The details of that would dictate who their official host is, and thus who is responsible for meeting them or arranging for them to be met.

Answer (score 1):

As Mr Tillerson would be a guest, and not part of the order of precedence of any other country.

The order of precedence is a ceremonial guide that suggests how people should be ordered for seating at dinner (for example). Mr Tillerson would be sat with his host. If Mr Tillerson were visiting India as a guest of the Prime Minister, he would be sat with Mr Modi. The same applies to Sri Lanka.

Comment: Yes. But, who will receive him when he arrives in New Delhi airport?

Comment: That would be a matter to be decided by the host country. There is no rule, ceremonial or otherwise. There is no requirement that he is met by any particular person. Anyway I now see that you're back on your hobby horse. The answer stays - Not in order of precedence, any ceremonial would be decided in ad hoc way.

Comment: @JamesK - i'm pretty sure there are protocol rules. I know there are some in USA.